# libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, libcrypto

Am performing ARM cross compilation on x86 and i have a tool chain like below :

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)    
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)    
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)`
```

I have written own script to cross compile my code to generate binaries. Inside my script, I have installed following tools:

```
apt-get install -y debootstrap build-essential cmake libssl-dev:armhf gcc-arm-linux* g++-arm-linux*  openssl:armhf libssl-dev:armhf curl:armhf libcurl4-gnutls-dev:armhf libtirpc-dev:armhf
```

I have openssl 1.1.1f installed on my ubuntu 18.04 OS, While running my script, I get below error:

```
libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
```

**NOTE : This libcrypto.so library is built by me on ubuntu 20.04 and now cross compilation is done on ubuntu 18.04**

Answer (score 0):

Your libcrypto.so is making a reference to a function from glibc (the basic library for everything) version 2.28, which was present during your build on 20.04, but now you're building on 18.04 with a different, incompatible version of glibc.

The path of least resistance is probably to rebuild openssl with your current toolchain.

Comment: Can you guide me install that glibc ?

Comment: You can only have one glibc version in a system at a time. Changing it would fix libcrypto, sure. And it would break everything else. If you want a serious learning experience, sure, go for it. I don't think I would do so myself.

Comment: In my cross compilation script, am already installing following tools: `apt-get install -y debootstrap build-essential cmake libssl-dev:armhf gcc-arm-linux* g++-arm-linux*  openssl:armhf libssl-dev:armhf curl:armhf libcurl4-gnutls-dev:armhf libtirpc-dev:armhf`. But still am getting error defined in above question